# OpenAI GPT-3 API errors: 'text' does not exist TS(2339) & 'prompt' does not exist on type 'CreateChatCompletion' TS(2345)

Tags: next.js, openai-api, gpt-3

```
import openai from "./zggpt";

const query = async (prompt:string,  chatId:string, model:string) => {
    const res= await openai
    .createChatCompletion({
        model,
        prompt,
        temperature: 0.9,
        
        top_p:1,
       
        max_tokens:1000,
        frequency_penalty:0,
        presence_penalty:0,
    })
    .then((res) => res.data.choices[0].text)
    .catch((err)=>
    `ZG was unable to find an answer for that!
     (Error: ${err.message})`
     );
     return res;
};

export default query;
```

Property 'text' does not exist on type 'CreateChatCompletionResponseChoicesInner'.ts(2339)

Argument of type '{ model: string; prompt: string; temperature: number; top_p: number; max_tokens: number; frequency_penalty: number; presence_penalty: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreateChatCompletionRequest'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'prompt' does not exist in type 'CreateChatCompletionRequest'.ts(2345)

even though I do everything as in the video, I get these errors.

i'm a beginner in coding, so I'm trying to make applications based on videos to learn.

Thanks

the application responds without returning an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmkT3.png)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6Hq_EX2LLM&t=6293s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You watched a tutorial which used the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint where you need to provide the prompt and parameters to get a completion). In this case, this is the function which generates a completion:

```
openai.createCompletion()
```

Whereas, you used the code from the tutorial, **but used the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) endpoint** (you need to provide the chat message to get a completion). In this case, this is the function which generates a completion:

```
openai.createChatCompletion()
```

*Note: OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. Among other things, there are changes in method names. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).*

| API endpoint | NodeJS function (SDK `v3`) | NodeJS function (SDK `v4`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chat Completions API | openai.createChatCompletion | openai.chat.completions.create |
| Completions API | openai.createCompletion | openai.completions.create |

#### Solution

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

Change this...

```
openai.createChatCompletion()
```

...to this.

```
openai.createCompletion()
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

Change this...

```
openai.chat.completions.create
```

...to this.

```
openai.completions.create
```

Both errors will disappear.

#### My advice

However, you want to achieve a chat-like bot using a GPT-3 model. At the time the tutorial was recorded, this was the only way to do it. Since 1 March 2023, the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model is available. I strongly suggest you to use it. See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Rok is correct, but also in the past 2 days OpenAI has released the ChatGPT model and endpoint.

Ref: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create?lang=python

In the Chat endpoint your code would look like this:

```
import openai;
import os;
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY");

const query = async (prompt:string,  chatId:string, model:string) => {
    const res= await openai
    .createChatCompletion({
        model:"gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages:[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    })
    .then((res) => res.choices[0].message)
    .catch((err)=>
    `ZG was unable to find an answer for that!
     (Error: ${err.message})`
     );
     return res;
};

export default query;
```